# How to manually change page numbering in beamer?

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I added some slides with `\pdfpages` and `\includepdf` command in the middle of the presentation. Now, I want to set the numbering of the following slides, so it matches with actual enumeration. How can it be done?

It's a simple question, yet I haven't seen it addressed on this site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume your frames probably don't show the pagenumbers, but the framenumbers (this is true for the default themes). You can manipulate this counter e.g. by using `\addtocounter{framenumber}{42}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\addtocounter{framenumber}{42}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```